# What is the latex code for the symbol "two colons and equals sign"?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators

I wish to use the symbol as in the following picture, however, I can not find it. Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried for finding the symbol (so people don't have to duplicate your efforts)?

Comment: In particular, you should look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/86 and see if you can find it using one of the methods there.  If you can't, you should say so in the question.

Comment: I use this tool http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html, and also I have tried to find in some documents which map the symbols to latex code. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Don't think this is in the Detexify database (doesn't seem to cover the necessary packages)

Answer (score 18):

The symbols is called `\Coloneqq` in the package `txfonts`/`pxfonts`. Here is the rest of the symbols:

[image]

Answer (score 13):

mathtools package has these symbols with the following argument

> The font packages `txfonts` and `pxfonts` provides various symbols that include a verti
>   cally centered colon but with tighter spacing. For example, the combination `:=` exists
>   as the symbol `\coloneqq` which typesets as `<tighter symbol picture>` instead of `<larger symbol picture>`. The primary disadvantage of using these fonts are the support packages’ lack of support for
>   `amsmath` (and thus `mathtools`) and worse yet, the side-bearings are way too tight; see [4] for examples. If you’re not using these fonts, `mathtools` provides the symbols for you.

Here is a sample

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}

\[\coloneqq \Coloneqq \coloneq \Coloneqq
\eqqcolon \Eqqcolon \eqcolon \Eqcolon
\colonapprox \Colonapprox \colonsim \Colonsim
\dblcolon
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `newtx` and `newpx` replace `txfonts` and `pxfonts` (respectively), with far better metrics (inc. sidebearings).  doesn't help with the interaction with `amsmath`, though, afaik