# How to typeset ::= correctly

Tags: symbols

How can I typeset the equality symbol `::=` used in the definition of syntactic categories of BNF grammars?

I would like to use it both in typewriter font (using `\texttt`) and in math mode.

Both `\texttt{::=}` and `$::=$` (or `$:\coloneqq$`) are ugly.

Comment: Have you tried `$\operatorname{::=}$` in math mode, it looks a little bit better maybe?

Comment: Another version is `$\Coloneqq$`from the package `\usepackage{txfonts}` as well as others [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121363/what-is-the-latex-code-for-the-symbol-two-colons-and-equals-sign)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\Coloneqq}{\mathrel{\vcenter{\hbox{$:$}}{\coloneqq}}}

\begin{document}

    \[ A \Coloneqq B \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I looked up for that symbol in the Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List but I wasn't able to find it out. Also detexify didn't help (don't know if it was for my poor drawing skill or if it is not aware of that symbol).